# How to deal with inner dependencies for apklib in maven (Android project)?

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, library-project, apklib

I faced following issue. Sometimes I want to add dependency to apklib in my Android project, but if this library has own dependencies that are not declared in its own pom file I get the error.

For example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maps-utils-apklib</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

it links us to http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/maps/android/android-maps-utils-apklib/0.3/android-maps-utils-apklib-0.3.pom

It's really need for correct work following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2_r2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>19.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

that are missing in `android-maps-utils-apklib-0.3.pom`

So, after I add `android-maps-utils-apklib` dependency, IDE tells me that this apklib needs own dependencies (e.g. android core that is already added to root project).

[image]

It means that I have my own project (PROJ) that has some adpklib dependency (D), where D needs some libs D1, D2, D3. They are not declared in pom file for D, but they are declared in pom for PROJ but it doesn't help.

**So the question is how I can add missing dependencies for D?**

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I've had the same problem.  Are you using IntelliJ/Android Studio?